# boolean type - String Contains checking in Java

Tags: java, boolean

below method boolean value always goes with false please look into my code

```
public void customerUserCreationAdd(String state, String zip,
            String isAdmin) throws InterruptedException {
        pui = new Polled(driver);

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.user_state).perform();
        pui.user_state.clear();
        pui.user_state.sendKeys(state);

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.user_zip).perform();
        pui.user_zip.clear();
        pui.user_zip.sendKeys(zip);

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.userReadonly).perform();
        boolean ed = isAdmin.equals("IsReadOnlyNo");
        if (ed == true) {
            pui.userReadonly.click();           
        }
        else {
        pui.Btn_userSave.click();       
        }
    }
```

from the above method all the parameter value (i.e state, zip, isAdmin) collecting from another class file,
 based on the isAdmin String value will mapped with two condition (true / false)
so while check the isAdmin value always execute with false statement

at the same time passing the isAdmin value directly  (inside the method) condition checked  correctly
let me know the reason why boolean condition not working with parameter value  or please point out my error

Comment: Why on Earth `ed == true` where a simple `ed` is enough?

Comment: @Prabu can you just `syso` the value of `isAdmin` before comparing

Comment: @singhal : yes i do the syso before comparing values are correct

Comment: @Prabu syso isAdmin and also syso ed just before you check if.And check  do you have some blank char or case senstivie? or something.

Comment: @singhal: thanks, i checked all the possible cases (case, trim, empty) but not working correctly

Comment: @Prabu, have you syso in the if{} else{} statement to make sure they are entring the wrong condition statement rather than your userReadonly.click() have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Declare another String variable inside the method and assign a parameter value in that String and Proceed its working fine

Code

```
public void customerUserCreationAdd(String state, String zip,
            String isAdmin) throws InterruptedException {
        pui = new Polled(driver);

        String isAdmin1 = isAdmin
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.user_state).perform();
        pui.user_state.clear();
        pui.user_state.sendKeys(state);

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.user_zip).perform();
        pui.user_zip.clear();
        pui.user_zip.sendKeys(zip);

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pui.userReadonly).perform();
        boolean ed = isAdmin1.equals(isAdmin);
        if (ed == true) {
            pui.userReadonly.click();           
        }
        else {
        pui.Btn_userSave.click();       
        }
    }
```

Comment: you use a string to equals with it self, certainly it will return true. But now, it will never become false now!

Answer (score -2):

```
if (ed) {
            pui.userReadonly.click();           
        }
```

This will be sufficient..

I think `IsReadOnlyNo` that you are using should be a boolean variable. So, you have to check like this:

```
boolean ed = isAdmin.equals(IsReadOnlyNo);
```

Comment: This doesn't semantically change the code, nor does it answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Matt Ball I have edited the answer now..